# React & TS - Remove nested array without deleting its objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

For some reasons, I have this kind of data :

```
const data = [{
    "0": {
        "Folder1": "Folder1"
    },
    "1": {
        "Folder2": "Folder2"
    },
    "Name": "Test.pdf",
    "Version": 1,
    "Created at": "22/06/2021, 17:39"
}]
```

What I want is to remove nested arrays ("0" and "1") so it looks like

```
const data = [{
    "Folder1": "Folder1"
    "Folder2": "Folder2"
    "Name": "Test.pdf",
    "Version": 1,
    "Created at": "22/06/2021, 17:39"
}]
```

What did I try?

```
Object.fromEntries(data)
```

```
data.flatMap((d) => ({data}))
```

I am using typescript, I am free to use any package if needed.

Thank you.

Comment: You say you are using typescript, what datatype is the `data` variable?

Comment: All you need is `delete data[0]["0"];` and `delete data[0]["1"];` (also, there are no nested arrays anywhere, those are objects)

Comment: Check the lodash merge and mergeWith methods: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge

Comment: const data: {
    [x: string]: string | undefined;
}[]

Comment: I can't do data[0]['0], TypeScript doesn't like it

Comment: Is your JSON always be the same as above or it could change?

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the items to flatten out and spread accordingly.

```
data.map(d => {
  let res = {};

  Object.keys(d).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof d[key] === "object") {
      res = {
        ...d[key],
        ...res,
      }
      delete d[key];
    }
  }) 



  return {
    ...res,
    ...d,
  }
})
```

Comment: I have a little error "Spreads can only be create from objects types" at
res = {
...d[key]

Comment: Do check this out, and check if you get the same error.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-gttcdj

Answer (score 0):

"0" and 1" are not arrays in your object. They are properties which have objects again.
You can use the `delete` operator, along with `Object.entries()`.

```
data.map((x) => {
  let a = Object.entries(x["0"]);
  let b = Object.entries(x["1"]);
  
  delete x["0"];
  delete x["1"];
  
  x[a[0]] = a[1];
  x[b[0]] = b[1];

});
```

Comment: I can't use x["0"], typescript doesn't allow it.

Comment: Can you add your type definitions in your code?

Comment: It would be better if i don't need to

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The problem was around a previous map in data generation. I needed to use array.reduce instead.

Thank you all for your answers.